# DB2 Integer to Decimal

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to cast integer to decimal, when its zero it is cast as a decimal. But, when it's not zero it stays an integer.

```
 Cast(COALESCE(td.BILL_100_CNT ,0)* 100 AS DECIMAL(31,2)) as Denomination_Amount
```

Comment: Your cast is quite clear.  If it is not going to a decimal, then DB2 has an error in this area.  My guess is that you are misinterpreting the results.

Comment: How do you determine that the value "stays integer"?

Comment: The output for 0: 0.00

Comment: The output for 100 is: 100 not 100.00

Comment: The column data type (integer or decimal) has nothing to do with the output formatting. I guess whatever tool you use to produce your "output" doesn't do a good job of formatting numbers.